# A better way to write something like groupby?

Tags: python

I know there's a groupby iterable in itertools, and, out of curiosity, I set to write my own implementation.

Two criteria I care about are readability (and being pythonic) followed by efficiency (not going over the sequence twice, for example).

I came up with two implementations, one satisfies the former criterion, and the second the latter:

```py
def my_groupby(container):
    for idx, target_key in enumerate(container):
        if idx > 0 and target_key == container[idx - 1]:
            continue
        yield (curr_key for curr_key in takewhile(lambda key: key == target_key, container[idx:]))


class my_groupby2:
    class _my_group:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self._parent = parent

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self._parent._curr_idx == self._parent._container_len:
                raise StopIteration
            curr_key = self._parent._container[self._parent._curr_idx]
            if curr_key != self._parent._target_key:
                self._parent._target_key = curr_key
                raise StopIteration
            self._parent._curr_idx += 1
            return curr_key

    def __init__(self, container):
        self._container = container
        self._target_key = container[0]
        self._container_len = len(container)
        self._curr_idx = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._curr_idx == self._container_len:
            raise StopIteration
        return self._my_group(self)
```

I was wondering if there's a better way of implementing it, in order to achieve both goals at once.

Comment: post this question to [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you will find better suggestion there

Comment: You can also check the ['roughly equivalent' implementation in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, the roughly equivalent implementation does look better than my second try, while still iterating only once on each element. The best improvement there is returning a generating member function instead of my inner iterator.